# Folder Access denied error when trying to create a file from a web project

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have solution in which there are two projects one is a web project and one is a windows application. The windows application does some file read write things. Recently I have got a requirement to refer those in Web project. I referred the windows project in my web project and it worked great.

But the issue is there is a file writing part in Windows Project which is triggering an Access Denied error. When I am running locally its not triggering that file error. When running from IIS that error triggers.

Comment: Does the frolder, that contains file have an access for IIS users? Rights should be the same as for the root folder of web project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign Write access to `IIS_IUSRS` user group in that folder. Just right click on the folder, go to security tab and add `IIS_IUSRS` with read + write access and click OK.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more details or if this solution was helpful.

Comment: Really sorry for the delay in reply.. I missed to mention server is Windows 2012r2. IIS 8.5. Im not able to find IIS_USRS user group in security popup user selection

Comment: @SandeepThomas You need to click on `Location...` button and select your computer from the tree view. This user group is only available on your machine. Have you tried it?

Comment: @SandeepThomas Doesn't matter where the folder is, You have to select your machine (which is running IIS).

Comment: @SandeepThomas Did you resolved the issue?